# .htaccess - Double Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have set up a profile system, and currently the profiles are being redirected to

```
/user/<username>
```

using this htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /profile?username=$1 [NC]
```

So basically when a user edits their profile, it would normally be /profile?username=$1&mode=edit

How can I edit my htaccess code so that a user can edit their profile by doing the following:

```
/user/<username>/edit
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

I also understand that this question has been asked a lot, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? I see you have an example of one already, so I'm not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Well basically, I don't understand how exactly to redirect the "&mode=edit" part to just /edit on the end of the url: "/user/<username>/edit"

Comment: You already have `RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /profile?username=$1 [NC]`, try adding `RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/edit$ /profile?username=$1&mode=edit [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

Before this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /profile?username=$1 [NC]
```

add:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /profile?username=$1&mode=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I added that, and when I put /user/<username>/edit, it returns "Object not found" :/